# Convergent fraction for constant $e$?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I've just learned about e.  I am very much the novice and my problem is that while trying to calculate the convergent fractions for e.  For instance:

$${2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{2}{3+\cfrac{3}{4}}}}}$$

I end up with 144/53?

I was wondering are there specific steps that I'm missing?  For me I've been starting at the end of the continued fraction and working my way left.  For instance:

$\frac{3}{1} + \frac{3}{4}$

And get 15/4 and then:

$\frac{2}{1} / \frac{15}{4}$

Until I finish with 144/53, which I'm not seeing this anywhere as one of the first few convergents of e.

Comment: where is this list of convergent fractions? Typically we force the 'numerators' to be $1$ in standard form, which most lists I've seen use as well. I assume this is why you're getting different answers.

Comment: @RobertMastragostino thanks for the edit, I had just got the correct syntax on when it said you had already corrected it.  I'm going off wolfram for one, 2, 3 , 8/3, 11/4, 19/7,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using a [generalized continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction); the convergents that you normally see listed are those for the [standard continued fraction expansion of $e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representations_of_e), i.e., the one with $1$ for each numerator:

$$e=[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,\dots]\;.$$

This can also be written

$$[1;0,1,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,\dots]$$

to emphasize the pattern even more strongly.

Comment: This is what I had original started with but, somehow veered off course.  With this, I would take the integer of the divided fraction for the period and the decimals as the next divisor of 1?  I will need to use the generalized continued fraction if I want the numerators to be integers other than 1?

Comment: @tijko: Yes, as in [this calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Continued_fraction_expansions_of_.CF.80) of the first few figures in the continued fraction representation of $\pi$.

Comment: To get the fraction form we take the first number 2 over unity, then the next fraction would be the first period times numerator and denominator; adding unity to the numerator?